Ricci tensor of an arbitary Riemannian bundle $(E,g')$
Consider a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$. One can then equip $TM$ with the Levi-Civita connection and talk about the curvature tensor $R \in \Gamma(\Lambda^2 T^*M \otimes \text{End}(TM))$. The Ricci tensor will be the $(0,2)$-tensor obtained by contracting $R$ with $g$.
What about if we have some arbitary bundle with a another Riemannian metric $(E,g')$ over $M$ equipped with a connection $\nabla$. This gives us a way to talk about curvature $R_\nabla$ and hence we could in theory obtain something similar to the Ricci tensor, by contracting $R_\nabla$ with $g'$ right? Is this still called the Ricci tensor even when we don't consider the tangent bundle or what is this?

No. The Ricci tensor is something specific to connections on the tangent bundle (metric or no metric).
Let $(E,\pi,M)$ be any vector bundle equipped with a connection $\nabla$. The curvature is an $\text{End}(E)$-valued $2$-form on $M$, i.e it is a section of $\bigwedge^2(T^*M)\otimes \text{End}(E)$, or equivalently, it is a vector-bundle morphism $R:\bigwedge^2(TM)\to \text{End}(E)$. In terms of local frames, let $\{e_1,\dots, e_n\}$ be a local frame for $TM$, and $\{\xi_1,\dots,\xi_k\}$ a local frame for $E$. Then, we get components $R^{\alpha}_{\,\beta\,ij}$ such that
\begin{align}
R(e_i\wedge e_j)\cdot \xi_{\beta}=\sum_{\alpha}R^{\alpha}_{\,\beta\,ij}\,\xi_{\alpha}, 
\end{align}
where the $\cdot$ on the LHS being the evaluation of an endomorphism on a vector. In the special case of $E=TM$, the indices $\alpha,\beta$ (which are the ‘endomorphism indices’) and $i,j$ (the $2$-form indices) run over the same range $\{1,\dots, n:=\dim M\}$, and thus we can sum over $\alpha$ and $i$ to get the Ricci tensor $R_{\beta j}=\sum\limits_{ s}R^{s}_{\,\beta\,sj}$. Note very carefully the Ricci tensor is not the trace over $\alpha,\beta$; in the metric-compatible case, this trace would be $0$ due to the curvature form taking values in the Lie-algebra of the orthogonal group, i.e the skew-symmetric matrices, and hence has trace $0$… or said differently, it is due to the anti-symmetry in the first two indices of the $(0,4)$ version of the Riemann tensor $R_{abcd}$.
More abstractly, we can phrase the issue as follows. Regrouping the curvature $R$ slightly differently gives us a bilinear bundle morphism $\widetilde{R}:TM\oplus E\to \text{Hom}(TM,E)$,
\begin{align}
\widetilde{R}(x,\xi):= R(\bullet\wedge x)\cdot\xi=[z\mapsto R(z\wedge x)\cdot\xi].
\end{align}
Obviously $\widetilde{R}$ and $R$ contain the same amount of information since we’re just permuting things around. In the special case of $E=TM$, we are able to define a trace on the target, and it is this trace which is the Ricci tensor: $\text{Ric}:=\text{trace}_{\text{End}(TM)}\circ\widetilde{R}$ (note carefully that $\text{trace}_{\text{End}(TM)}\circ R$ is defined, but this is NOT the Ricci tensor; in the metric-compatible case this trace is identically $0$), which thus gives us a bilinear bundle morphism $TM\oplus TM\to M\times \Bbb{R}$. But of course, now we see the issue: if $E\neq TM$, then there is no natural trace on $\text{Hom}(TM,E)$, so we cannot define a ‘Ricci tensor’. Even if you have a bundle metric $g’$ on $E$, this still won’t help because $g’:E\oplus E\to \Bbb{R}$ doesn’t relate $E$ with $TM$. So, you’re going to need some mechanism to first identify $E$ with $TM$, and then you can take a trace to define a ‘Ricci tensor’, or even if you don’t have an isomorphism $TM\cong E$, you’re going to need some vector bundle map $\text{Hom}(TM,E)\to M\times\Bbb{R}$, which you can treat as a ‘generalized trace’; but again, this is extra structure.
So, in some sense, this is similar to how torsion can only be defined for connections on the tangent bundle (or in some other cases if you have a soldering form… which essentially means you can treat things as the tangent bundle) because in this case we have the special identity endomorphism $I_{TM}:TM\to TM$, which is a $TM$-valued $1$-form on $M$, and thus we are able to take the exterior-covariant derivative $\tau:= d_{\nabla}(I_{TM})$. But on a general vector bundle, there is no natural (non-trivial) $E$-valued $1$-form on $M$ (or equivalently, there’s no natural non-trivial section of $\text{Hom}(TM,E)$).
